# How to hyperlink text within a paragraph

Tags: html

[how it looks on the web right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74EmU.png)

```html
<div class="what-text2">
    <h2>How TIL works</h2>
    <p>Transforming the Instructional Landscape (TIL) brings a human-centred design thinking approach to classroom design. TIL
    identifies the needs of the University of Toronto community regarding classroom design and classroom technology and
    shares information across the university community. Led by an ongoing collaboration between </p>
    <a href="http://blogs.studentlife.utoronto.ca/innovationhub/files/2021/05/TIL_FinalApril2021_Compressed.pdf" target="_blank" class="news-link" overflow-wrap: break-word;> 
        <p>Learning Space Management</p>
    </a>
    <p>
    (LSM), Centre for Teaching Support & Innovation (CTSI) and the Innovation Hub, TIL aims to engage students, faculty and
    staff in discussions about opportunities for innovation in the university’s classrooms.</p>
</div>
```

I want to hyperlink a phrase within a paragraph, with the next portion of the paragraph on the same line. But I cannot find a way to that, even when i have only one p tag, with the a tag in the middle.

Comment: Get rid of the `<p>` tag around "Learning Space Management", and combine the other 2 `<p>` tags together.

Comment: ^ he got the answer, @SuperStormer just post an answer bruv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `span` instead of `paragraph` or as mentioned in the comments, get rid of paragraph. Span would be helpful in case you require specific styling of the parts of the text

```html
<div class="what-text2">
  <h2>How TIL works</h2>
  <span>Transforming the Instructional Landscape (TIL) brings a human-centred design thinking approach to classroom design. TIL
                identifies the needs of the University of Toronto community regarding classroom design and classroom technology and
                shares information across the university community. Led by an ongoing collaboration between </span>
  <a href="http://blogs.studentlife.utoronto.ca/innovationhub/files/2021/05/TIL_FinalApril2021_Compressed.pdf" target="_blank" class="news-link" overflow-wrap: break-word;>
    <span>Learning Space Management</span>
  </a>
  <span>
                (LSM), Centre for Teaching Support & Innovation (CTSI) and the Innovation Hub, TIL aims to engage students, faculty and
                staff in discussions about opportunities for innovation in the university’s classrooms.</span>
</div>
```

More on inline elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

```html
<div class="what-text2">
  <h2>How TIL works</h2>
Transforming the Instructional Landscape (TIL) brings a human-centred design thinking approach to classroom design. TIL
                identifies the needs of the University of Toronto community regarding classroom design and classroom technology and
                shares information across the university community. Led by an ongoing collaboration between
  <a href="http://blogs.studentlife.utoronto.ca/innovationhub/files/2021/05/TIL_FinalApril2021_Compressed.pdf" target="_blank" class="news-link" overflow-wrap: break-word;>
    Learning Space Management
  </a>
  
                (LSM), Centre for Teaching Support & Innovation (CTSI) and the Innovation Hub, TIL aims to engage students, faculty and
                staff in discussions about opportunities for innovation in the university’s classrooms.
</div>
Expand snippet
```